# iOS - twitter two-part post

Tags: ios, twitter

I have my app filling out the tweet sheet for the user and sometimes it may go over 140 characters including the url. I am trying to develop a method which can split the tweet into two parts and post part 2 first, and then part 1 so it will look like:

(1/2) blah blah blah

(2/2) blah blah blah

Here is the method I have so far:

```
(void)sendTweet:(NSString *)msg setURL:(NSString*)url setImg:(UIImage*)img {
    // Set up the built-in twitter composition view controller.
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

    // Set the initial tweet text. See the framework for additional properties that can be set.
    if (![tweetViewController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]])
        NSLog(@"Unable to add the URL!");

    if (![tweetViewController addImage:img])
        NSLog(@"Unable to add the image!");

    if (![tweetViewController setInitialText:msg])
        NSLog(@"Unable to add the message!");


    // Create the completion handler block.
    [tweetViewController setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
         NSString *output;

        switch (result) {
            case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                // The cancel button was tapped.
                output = @"Tweet cancelled.";
                break;
            case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                // The tweet was sent.
                output = @"Tweet sent.";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        // Show alert to see how things went...
        UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                                  initWithTitle:@"The Predictor" 
                                  message:output 
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];

        // Dismiss the tweet composition view controller.
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }];

    // Present the tweet composition view controller modally.
    [self presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];


}
```

Here is how i'm calling it, although the two part stuff isn't working...and I would like this functionality built-in to the method above.

```
if ([alertView tag] == 1) {
    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {
        NSString *theURL = @"PredictorApps.com";
        NSString *theTweet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@\n%@", [[Singleton sharedSingleton].spreadDate substringToIndex:5], theTitle, theMessage];
        if (([theURL length] + [theTweet length]) <= 120)
            [self sendTweet:theTweet setURL:theURL setImg:nil];
        else if (([theURL length] + [theTweet length]) > 120) {
            NSString *partTwo = [theTweet substringFromIndex:(([theURL length] + [theTweet length]) / 2)];
            NSLog(@"Part Two: %@", partTwo);
            [self sendTweet:partTwo setURL:theURL setImg:nil];
            NSString *partOne = [theTweet substringToIndex:(([theURL length] + [theTweet length]) / 2)];
            NSLog(@"Part One: %@", partOne);
            [self sendTweet:partOne setURL:theURL setImg:nil];

        }

    }

}
```

any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use URL shorteners for reduce the URL size to post in twitter of facebook...For that you can refer to this link..This is a simple coding to shortening any type of URL u have..So u can reduce 2 part of post into single..I hope this will help you....

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/02/04/iphone-coding-recipe-shortening-urls/

All the best....

Comment: afaik, twitter automatically shortens any URL to 19 chars. I ended up creating a recursive method to split the tweets into multiple parts if necessary using the tweet sheet.